# CodeIgniter: what is the scope of load->helper

Tags: codeigniter, frameworks

In a controller class I have this function:

```
public function index(){
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $data['title'] = 'News archive';
    $this->load->view('news/index', $data);
}
```

I load helper url because I'm using anchor() in news/index. So seems like it's enough to load helper in the parent function, and I don't have to load it inside news/index.

So my question is what's going on underneath CI that lets me do this? Is load->view a function, or is it pasting the result of executing news/index on $data? How is load->view aware of helper url having been loaded in index? I'm still trying to make sense of how the CI framework works.

Also what would be the best place to load helper, in the constructor, or in each function as we need it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Also what would be the best place to load helper, in the constructor, or in each function as we need it?
```

As a rough rule of thumb;

- If you use the helper once in a controller - place it in that specific function
- If you use the helper in multiple places in a controller - place it in that controllers constructor
- If you use the helper in multiple places in multiple controllers - place it in the 'autoload' section once.

Answer (score 1):

you can  get all the answer if u go through the Loader Class in codeigniter...

```
path >> system/core/loader.php
```

everything that is done is here....

and for ut last question . according to the user guide

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/loader.html

> loader, as the name suggests, is used to load elements. These elements can be libraries (classes) View files, Helpers, Models, or your own files.

so since it just loads the elements...
i usually(prefer) loading it in each function where needed. (unless i need the same elements in other functions too)